# How to decode JSON date using php?

Tags: php

I get from JSON output the date in JSON encrypt, I want to decode it when I insert it to mysql.

I insert the output:

```
"date": "/Date(1446739002960)/"
```

to $dateparse variable

I was write the solution using javascript:

```
var dateString = "\/Date(753343200000)\/".substr(6);
var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString ));
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
alert(date);
```

How can I decode the variable content using php?
thank you

Comment: Did you tried `json_decode($yourDate)`?

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget about timezone as JavaScript date string may include it and here is how you can parse it for both cases

```
// Let's assume you did JSON parsing and got your date string
$date = '/Date(1511431604000+0000)/';

// Parse the date to get timestamp and timezone if applicable
preg_match('/\/Date\(([0-9]+)(\+[0-9]+)?/', $date, $time);

// remove milliseconds from timestamp
$ts = $time[1] / 1000;
// Define Time Zone if exists
$tz = isset($time[2]) ? new DateTimeZone($time[2]) : null;

// Create a new date object from your timestamp
// note @ before timestamp
// and don't specify timezone here as it will be ignored anyway
$dt = new DateTime('@'.$ts);

// If you'd like to apply timezone for whatever reason
if ($tz) {
  $dt->setTimezone($tz);
}

// Print your date
print $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: A timestamp represents an absolute reference to a second or microsecond in time. Timezone is not relevant here. You would use timezone when representing the timestamp as a string in a local timezone.

Answer (score 4):

**1) Fix your JSON**

`$dateJSON ='{"date": "/Date(1446739002960)/"}'`

**2) Decode your JSON**

`$timestamp = json_decode($dateJSON, true);`

**3) Remove all non numeric characters**

`$timestamp = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $timestamp['date'])`

**4) Transform timestamp (divided by 1000 cause of JS date) to a human-readable format**

`$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp / 1000);`

Comment: $times="/Date(1446739002960)/";
$timestamp = json_decode($times);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo $date;

Comment: better go with Hasse Björk's answer. You need to remove all non numeric characters. And btw the timestamp is probaly wrong. You will get something like `47815-05-03 10:05:00`

Comment: You need to divide the JS-date with 1000 to get PHP-date... and change `json_decode($dateJSON, true);` to get an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your json code is not complete, you are missing the curly brackets needs to be filtered and passed through the json_decode and time functions:

```
// Curly brackets where missing
$obj = json_decode( '{"date": "/Date(753343200000)/"}' );

// Remove non numerical characters
$obj->date = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $obj->date );

// Divide javascript date (in ms) with 1000 to get UNIX date (seconds)
// Convert the date as DD-MM-YYYY 
$dateparse = date( 'd/m/Y', ( $obj->date / 1000 ) );
echo $dateparse;
```

**EDIT** Updated the date and corrected for JavaScript date

If you want time too, use `date( 'd/m/Y H:i:s', ( $obj->date / 1000 ) )`

Comment: work good, but the dates that I get after decode are invalids...
try please 753343200000, it need to be 15/11/1993

Comment: please see my javascript code in the question @Hasse

Comment: Ok, I changed the date format to your desired format dd/mm/yyyy and fixed a miss when converting JS-date to PHP-date. JavaScript is in milliseconds and PHP in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package to parse the JSON dates:

https://github.com/webapix/dot-net-json-date-formatter

```
use \Webapix\DotNetJsonDate\Date;

Date::toDateTime('/Date(1446739002960)/'); // return with \DateTime object
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem is the JSON date can also be in the format `'/Date(1511431604000+0000)/'`, so we need to ignore the +0000 if it exists, otherwise if we use `preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $json_date)`, 0000 is added to the timestamp:

```
$json_date = '/Date(1511431604000+0000)/'; // or $json_date = '/Date(1511431604000)/';   

// Parse date to get the timestamp and the timezone if set
preg_match('/\/Date\(([0-9]+)(\+[0-9]+)?/', $json_date, $time_array);

// Remove milliseconds from JSON timestamp to make it a Unix timestamp
$unix_timestamp = intval($time_array[1] / 1000);
```